# Opening up process and grabbing window title. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: vb.net, process

In my application I allow for the users to add a program from a open file dialog, and it then adds the item to a listview and saves the items location into the tag. So what I am trying to do is when the program in the listview is selected and the button is pressed, it starts a timer and this timer checks to see if the process is running, and if it isn't launches the process, and once the process is launched it gets the window title of the process and sends it to a textbox on another form.

**EDIT:
The question is if anyone can see why it is not working, by this I mean starting the process, then when it's started closing the form and adding the process window title to a textbox on another form.
I have tried to get it working but I can't. I know that the process name it is getting is right I think my problem is to do with my for loop. Basically it isn't doing anything visible right now.**

I feel like I am very close with my code and im hoping it just needs a couple minor tweaks. Any help would be appreciated. Sorry if my coding practices aren't that great, im pretty new to this.

**EDIT:I found solution. I added code to the button that enables my timer to execute the process. Also another problem was indeed the way it read the file, I had to use the replace function  to remove the ".exe" from the filepath code.

EDIT 2 : A better solution has been posted by Mark Hall. I am now using his code as it has less chance for error.

```
    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
       Dim s As String = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Tag
    Dim myFile As String = Path.GetFileName(s)
    Dim mu As String = myFile.Replace(".exe", "").Trim()
    Dim f As Process
    Dim p As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName(mu)

    For Each f In p
        If p.Length > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To p.Length - 1
                ProcessID = (p(i).Id)
                AutoMain.Name.Text = f.MainWindowTitle
                Timer1.Enabled = False
                Me.Close()
            Next
        Else
            ProcessID = 0
            End If
        If ProcessID = 0 Then
            Process.Start(mu)
        End If
    Next
    End Sub
```

Comment: oops, I realize I made more of a statement. The question is if anyone can see why it is not working, by this I mean starting the process, then when it's started closing the form and adding the process window title to a textbox on another form.

Comment: Are you trying to start a single item or multiple Items?

Comment: Just a single item. I only allow for 1 item to be selected. I thought I found a solution to my problem though. Apparently it was the process name, it contained .exe so I had to replace it..but it only works now if the process has been started already. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that you are looking for a Process that matches your parameters before you enter your For Each loop the Process array is empty so it never enters it, therefore you never start your process.

This is a very quick example that works:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Dim s As String = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Tag.ToString
    Dim myFile As String = Path.GetFileName(s)

    Dim p As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName(Path.ChangeExtension(myFile, Nothing))
    Static started As Boolean

    If p.Count > 0 Or started Then
        If p.Length > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To p.Length - 1
                ProcessId = (p(0).Id)
                AutoMain.Name.Text = p(0).MainWindowTitle
                Timer1.Enabled = False
                started = False
                Timer1.Stop()
                Me.Close()
            Next
        Else
            ProcessId = 0
        End If
    Else
        started = True
        Process.Start(myFile)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks again Mark. Your solution is a little smoother than mine.

Comment: @user1632018 Glad to be of help